# using python to scrape data from a tag that comes after a specific text on a website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping

So, I'm scraping some data from a website that was built strangely,
I have this part of the code to scrap the data:

```
   # Find the span that contains the English name
    try:
        english_name_tag = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="infoTag1"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span[2]')
        english_name = english_name_tag.text
    except:
        english_name = '-'

        # Find the span that contains the English name
    try:
        rating_tag = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Div1"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[2]')
        rating_name = rating_tag.text
    except:
        rating_name = '-'
```

and here's part of the source code:

```
<div style="line-height: 24px; text-align: right" align="right">
            <span id="QuickNav">
                <a style="color:#3095b4;font-weight:bold;"><i class="fa fa-align-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>ניווט מהיר</a>
                <div id="CompanyNavBar" style="border:#3095b4 1px solid;border-bottom:0px; display: none; position: absolute; top: 145px;">

                    
                    <div class="CompanyNav"><a href="#Div23">נתונים עסקיים</a></div>
                    <div class="CompanyNav"><a href="#Div8">מנהלים</a></div>
                    

                    
                    
                    <div class="CompanyNav"><a href="#infoTag2">מודיעין עסקי</a></div>
                    <div class="CompanyNav t5"><a href="#compDetailsDunsScore">דנסקור</a></div>
                    <div class="CompanyNav"><a href="#compDetailsTreeStatic">עץ בעלויות</a></div>
                    <div class="CompanyNav"><a href="#infoTag7">בעלות והנהלה</a></div>
                    <div class="CompanyNav show_mobile"><a href="#neworder">כלים</a></div>

                </div>
            </span>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">

                                <img src="/ShowImage?d_number=0" style="max-width: 210px; max-height: 90px; padding-bottom: 10px">

                            <div class="company_name">
עזריאלי אי קומרס בע"מ                            </div>
known as:  <span dir="ltr"> טיול במאדים </span>
                                <br>
second name:  <span dir="ltr"> צטיילים במאדים </span>
                                <br>
english name:  <span dir="ltr"> MARS TRIP </span>
                                <br>

                            <span class="comp_active">Active</span>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="1" valign="top" align="left" nowrap="">

                            <a style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; display: inline; color: #aaaaaa; font-size: 13px">
                                        <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="ManageFollow(this)">
                                            <img src="/img/star.png" class="favoritePng" style="width: 50px !important" duns="532450587" isinfollow="false" onclick="ManageFollow(this);updateAnalytics('event', 'Click', {'event_category': 'CompanysCard', 'event_label': 'AddMonitor'});">
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="followTxt" duns="532450587">follow</span>
                                        </span>



                            </a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 20%; font-weight: bold; height: 30px">address</td>
                            <td style="width: 69%; height: 30px">mars colony, 12345, mars</td>
                        </tr>
                                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 20%; font-weight: bold; height: 30px">Phone</td>
                            <td style="width: 69%; height: 30px;direction:ltr">
123-456789                                    <br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 20%; font-weight: bold; height: 30px">email</td>
                            <td style="width: 69%; height: 30px"><a href="mailto:annonym@gmail.com">mailto:annonym@gmail.com</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 20%; font-weight: bold; height: 30px"> Business category:</td>
                            <td style="width: 69%; height: 30px">Food Industry, Packaging</td>
                        </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>




        </div>
```

the find_element by xpath taking the second span inside the TD,
I want it to instead, take the text from the span that comes after the text "english name:",
how can I do that? I'm sure its pretty simple yet still can't find the way :(

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for the desired text in the table cell and take the `span` element following it.

```
english_name_tag = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                           '*//td/text()[normalize-space()="english name:"]'
                                           '/following-sibling::span')
```

Comment: It's very close to the solution that worked for me:


driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="infoTag1"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()[normalize-space()="english name:"]/following::span')

Comment: @lidorkalfa The solution works on the data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution that worked for me:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="infoTag1"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()[normalize-space()="english name:"]/following::span')
```